# REST call fails from service but not from WinForms-App

Tags: c#, web-services, service

I try to get some information via a REST call from a windows service (using the 'TimedHostedService' as found online). I start a timer in 'StartAsync' and call the method 'DoWork'. I made this as an 'async' method and called:

```
ICollection<Module> allModules = await client.GetModulesAsync();
```

This method was auto-generated by NSwag (So I guess it's correct :-) ). 
It uses an HttpClient to make a GET-request. GetModulesAsync:

```
var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/Modules");
var client_ = _httpClient;
try
{
   using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
   {
       request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");  request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));    
      PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
      var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
      request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
      PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);    
      var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false); //here it fails
...
```

It goes directly to the 'finally' of the try-finally when the 'SendAsync' (last code line) is called. In case I copy the whole stuff (including the DoWork and StartAsnc)  into a WinForms-App it all works. In the WinForms-App, I don't derive from IHostedService and IDisposable but keep the all the rest.

Comment: The exception is "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." And the inner one: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." I also added the method "NEVER_EAT_POISON_Disable_CertificationValidation()" to solve that issue but did not help. (As expected as it works in the Winforms-App)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard from this snippet to conclude the whole context of this method call (the one that make the ...SendAsync call), so it might be that the Task never waits for the async operation to complete, I suggest that you stall WhenAll() the task is completed or just ConfigureAwait(true) and observe the behavior then

Comment: Hm, I don't think that this is the problem as the method finishes, when I use it in the WinForms-App. There, I get a response and the code execution is followed by the next line as it should.